# Problem when using Crystal Ball function - Unexpected plot behaviour

Tags: python, scipy, physics, curve-fitting

I'm trying to use the Crystal Ball function to fit some energy spectra from calorimeter data. As it was my first time using it I tried some tests before. I checked the definition of the Crystal Ball function on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Ball_function) and in other literature and then implemented it through the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

def crystal_ball(x, alpha, n, mean, sigma, N):

    A = (n / abs(alpha)) ** n * np.exp(-0.5 * alpha ** 2)
    B =  n / abs(alpha) - abs(alpha)

    mask = ((x - mean) / sigma) > -alpha

    gaussian_part = N * norm.pdf(x[mask], loc = mean, scale = sigma)
    powerlaw_part = N * A / ((B - (x[~mask] - mean) / sigma) ** n)

    result = np.zeros_like(x)

    result[mask]  = gaussian_part
    result[~mask] = powerlaw_part        

    return result, mask

# Example usage:
x_values = np.linspace(-10, 4, 1000)
alpha_val = 1
n_val = 10
mean_val = 0
sigma_val = 1
N_val = 1

y_values = crystal_ball(x_values, alpha_val, n_val, mean_val, sigma_val, N_val)[0]

mask = crystal_ball(x_values, alpha_val, n_val, mean_val, sigma_val, N_val)[1]

plt.plot(x_values, y_values, c = 'b', marker = '*', ms = 1, ls = '',
         label = f'Crystal Ball (α={alpha_val}, n={n_val}, μ={mean_val}, σ={sigma_val})')

plt.plot(x_values[mask], y_values[mask], c = 'g', marker = '*', ms = 1, ls = '',
         label = 'gauss')

plt.plot(x_values[~mask], y_values[~mask], c = 'r', marker = '*', ms = 1, ls = '',
         label = 'exp')

plt.vlines(-alpha_val, 0, 1, colors = 'orange', lw = 1)

plt.xlabel('Invariant Mass')
plt.ylabel('Probability Density')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But when plotting I get an unexpected discontinuity:

[image: my crystalball plot]

It is as if the power-law part of the function is multiplied by a scale factor that I can neither find nor interpret. Can somebody explain the reason for this behavior or at least show me the error in my code?

In practice, I would like to obtain a continuous curve.

I also tried using the `scipy.stats.crystalball` module but it turned out to be even more complicated and not useful.

Comment: Is that supposed to be "guess" or "Gauss"?

Comment: It was Gauss, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you created inconsistent values. As per the Wikipedia page, you only have control over the values for `alpha`, `n`, `xbar`, and `sigma`, but you set `N` as well when that value should actually be determined by the other values. If you remove your `N` definition and generate all the values per the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Ball_function), then you get the correct result.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import erf

plt.close("all")

def crystal_ball(x, alpha, n, xbar, sigma):
    n_over_alpha = n/abs(alpha)
    exp = np.exp(-0.5*alpha ** 2)
    A = (n_over_alpha)**n*exp
    B =  n_over_alpha - abs(alpha)
    C = n_over_alpha/(n-1)*exp
    D = np.sqrt(0.5*np.pi)*(1 + erf(abs(alpha)/np.sqrt(2)))
    N = 1/(sigma*(C + D))

    mask = (x - xbar)/sigma > -alpha

    gaussian = N*np.exp(-0.5*((x[mask]-xbar)/sigma)**2)
    powerlaw = N*A*(B - (x[~mask]-xbar)/sigma)**-n

    result = np.zeros_like(x)
    result[mask] = gaussian
    result[~mask] = powerlaw
    # or
    # result = np.concatenate((powerlaw, gaussian))

    return result, mask

x = np.linspace(-10, 4, 1000)
alpha = 1
n = 10
xbar = 0
sigma = 1

y, mask = crystal_ball(x, alpha, n, xbar, sigma)

plt.plot(x[mask], y[mask], label="gauss")
plt.plot(x[~mask], y[~mask], label="exp")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Now, you seem to have understated the usefulness of scipy's `crystallball` function. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.crystalball.html) you will see that what they call `beta` is what you call `alpha` and what they call `m` is what you call `n`. The documentation also says,

> The probability density above is defined in the "standardized" form. To shift and/or scale the distribution use the `loc` and `scale` parameters. Specifically, `crystalball.pdf(x, beta, m, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to `crystalball.pdf(y, beta, m) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

In other words, they have completely implemented what you are looking for, they just name things differently (`loc` is `xbar` and `scale` is `sigma`).

Here is a comparison between the results. They are identical.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy import stats

# same 'crystal_ball' function as before

x = np.linspace(-10, 4, 100)
alpha = 1
n = 10
xbar = 0
sigma = 1

y, mask = crystal_ball(x, alpha, n, xbar, sigma)
y_scipy = stats.crystalball.pdf(x, beta=alpha, m=n, loc=xbar, scale=sigma)

plt.plot(x[mask], y[mask], "x", label="gauss")
plt.plot(x[~mask], y[~mask], "x", label="exp")
plt.plot(x, y_scipy, label="scipy")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Jared. I probably messed up due to the fact that I didn't stick completely to the wikipedia definition, as you kindly pointed out. Now I understood and fixed my code. Best regards